# Powershell send email failure

Tags: outlook, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a Powershell email feature, I used comdle

```
"Send-MailMessage -To mail -From mail -Subject"
```

I'm getting the error:

**Unable to connect to the remote server.**

Also, I wonder if this method works?

```
New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($From, $To, $Subject, $Body)
```

and what's the difference with Send-MailMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to check your SMTP and see if you can parse or ping your SMTP server. Also, Have you checked your port e.g. 587 ? Like this:

Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -cc $cc -Subject $sub -Body $body -Credential $mycreds -SmtpServer $smtp -DeliveryNotificationOption Never -BodyAsHtml -UseSsl -port 587

For the send email difference, you can also refer to the following link:

[Scripting: Send email using Powershell and System.Net.Mail API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2017/08/30/code-send-email-using-powershell-system-net-mail-api/)